# Select * or Equivalent in Scala Query

Tags: scala, scalaquery

I've got this ScalaQuery model in Playframework 2

```
object User {
    implicit object UserFormat extends Format[User] {
    def reads(json: JsValue) : User = User(
        None,
        (json \ "firstName").as[String],
        (json \ "lastName").as[String],
        (json \ "email").as[String]
    )

    def writes(user: User) : JsValue = JsObject(Seq(
        "firstName" -> JsString(user.firstName),
        "lastName" -> JsString(user.lastName),
        "email" -> JsString(user.email))
    )
    }
}

object UsersTable extends Table[User]("users") {
    def id = column[Long]("USER_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def fName = column[String]("USER_FIRSTNAME", O.NotNull)
    def lName= column[String]("USER_LASTNAME", O.NotNull)
    def email = column[String]("USER_EMAIL", O.NotNull)

    def user_email_idx = index("user_email_idx", email, unique = true)

    def * =  id.? ~ fName ~ lName ~ email <> (User.apply _, User.unapply _)
    def forInsert = fName ~ lName ~ email <> ({ (f, l, e) => User(None, f, l, e) }, { u:User => Some((u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email)) })
}
```

I'd like to perform a Select * and return all the rows in `UsersTable`. Is it possible to do this using the UsersTable projection? I've seen some examples that look like this

```
        UsersTable.where(_.fName startsWith "H").list
```

to select rows that fit a criteria. How do I do this without passing in any of that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you should need to do is this:

```
val query = for(r <- MyTable) yield r
val results = query.list
```

The first line creates the actual query object that represents something like `select * from MyTable`, and the second line actual invokes that and loads the results into memory.

The important implicits you might want to know about are `tableToQuery`, which lets the `MyTable` have for-comprehensions on it; and `queryToQueryInvoker`, which pimps the query so that it has methods like `list`.

Alternatively you should be able to do something like

```
val query: Query[User] = MyTable
```

which should use the `tableToQuery` implicit to satisfy the type requirement.

Comment: lovely answer with all the details i need to support myself in future. you get the cookie!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for: https://github.com/szeiger/scalaquery-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalaquery/examples/FirstExample.scala#L73

See also http://scalaquery.org/doc/api/scalaquery-0.9.4/#org.scalaquery.ql.Query for all the methods of the `Query` class.

You can also use for-comprehensions to query your tables:

```
for {
  record <- MyTable if record.column0 === "foo"
} yield record.column1 ~ record.column2
```

Comment: isn't there a way to extract this from `UsersTable`? I'd like to build a list of row values and pass it to `Json.generate(...)`

Comment: What do you mean with "extract this"?

Answer (score 0):

I've done it for now with `val userQuery = UsersTable.where(_.email =!= "")`. But I'm sure this isn't the best answer. So keeping this open.