# Cannot get same number of rows by equivalent slick query

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

Following is the Postgresql query and it returns 400+ rows

```
SELECT 
*

FROM 
investors, 
investments, 
investor_personal_information,
sub_products, 
products, 
company, 
issuers, 
investment_admin_approvals, 
users

WHERE 
investments.investor_id = investor_personal_information.id AND
investments.investor_id = investors.id AND 
investments.sub_product_id = sub_products.id AND 
sub_products.product_id = products.id AND 
products.company_id = company.id AND 
investments.id = investment_admin_approvals.investment_id AND 
issuers.owner = users.id
```

I've written its equivalent Slick query in Scala

```
val query = {
  val baseQuery = Investments join InvestorPersonalInformation on {
    case (its, ipi) => its.investorId === ipi.id
  } join Investors on {
    case ((its, ipi), irs) => its.investorId === irs.id
  } join SubProducts on {
    case (((its, ipi), irs), sbp) => its.subProductId === sbp.id
  } join Products on {
    case ((((its, ipi), irs), sbp), pds) => sbp.productId === pds.id
  } join Tables.Company on {
    case (((((its, ipi), irs), sbp), pds), cpy) => pds.companyId === cpy.id
  } join Tables.Issuers on {
    case ((((((its, ipi), irs), sbp), pds), cpy), iss) => cpy.issuerId === iss.id
  } join InvestmentAdminApprovals on {
    case (((((((its, ipi), irs), sbp), pds), cpy), iss), iaa) => its.id === iaa.investmentId
  } join Users on {
    case ((((((((its, ipi), irs), sbp), pds), cpy), iss), iaa), usrs) => iss.owner === usrs.id
  } map {
    case ((((((((its, ipi), irs), sbp), pds), cpy), iss), iaa), usrs) => (its, ipi, irs, sbp, pds, cpy, iss, iaa, usrs)
  }

  baseQuery
}
```

When I run `db.run(query.result)` I get only 12 rows. I am using inner join in both queries and both are equivalent. What can be root cause of this?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799540/select-or-equivalent-in-scala-query

Comment: Your slick query is quite hard to read. Are you sure you didn't mess up a variable? Have you considered using a monadic join instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are slick 3.0 and above. Print the sql statement generated by slick and compare with your raw sql query.

Following code will help you get the sql generated by slick

```
query.result.statements.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 2):

The SQL query doesn't contain the join on `company.issuer_id = issuers.id`.